# How can I track down physical gold bought by my grandpa, but held by the bank?

Tags: investing, gold, receipt

My understanding is that my Grandpa and Grandma bought a gold bar or a portion of a gold bar and were issued a receipt and the gold was either held by the bank that facilitated the deal or a third party. I am still getting details on which bank they went through and what bank acquired that bank etc... but my main question is:

What resources or options are available for tracking down this type of gold purchase? Are banks mandated to keep records on this type of thing and obligated reach out to the owner of the property?

Comment: I'm confused - what kind of gold did he buy, and what do you think he did with it?  For instance, did he buy actual gold coins or bars?  He could have taken them home and buried them in the back yard, or sold them and spent the money, or anything - the bank would have nothing to do with this after he bought it.  So how do you think the bank is involved?

Comment: My understanding is that my grandpa and grandma bought the gold and were issued a receipt and the gold was either held by the bank that facilitated the deal or a third party. I am still getting details on which bank they went through and what bank acquired that bank etc... but my main question is what resources or options are available for tracking this down. Are banks mandated to keep records on this type of thing and obligated reach out to the owner of the property?

Comment: Oh just a follow up,  I believe it was a gold bar or a portion of a gold bar

Comment: You might check with your government's unclaimed property registry.  In the US this is handled by state governments.

Comment: @NateEldredge - you should make that an answer.   I'd vote for it. :)

Answer (score 3):

You might check with your government's unclaimed property registry. In the US this is handled by state governments.